# Phage base Biosensor

Tags: biotechnology

What kind of biosensor is made by Phages?
I need a list of published paper that used Phages for make LCR(inductance (L), capacitance (C), and resistance (R) of a component) biosensor for detection. for example detection of E.coli

Comment: If you are looking for the bacterial receptor that is used by phages then the following review may contain helpful info with respect to E.coli and the lambda phage. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3509688/

Comment: Hmm, No I am looking for application of these communication for making Biosensor for example immobilization a phage in a surface and use for detection a specific bacteria by attaching bacterial receptor to phage.

Comment: What is LCR? Ligase chain reaction? What is that? I suggest to elaborate your question, or at the very least explain (or better omit) acronyms.

Comment: @ChrisStronks An LCR meter is a piece of electronic test equipment used to measure the inductance (L), capacitance (C), and resistance (R) of a component.

Comment: So you want to immobilize phages on a surface, then use those to capture bacteria, then look for changes in electrical properties? Whole phages might not be necessary, antibodies against specific bacterial proteins might be easier to use.

Comment: This reminded me of something a friend of mine was working on, trying to attach antibodies to specific portions of a CD, then trying to detect protein binding with a standard CD drive. He hoped the proteins would change the reflection enough for the laser to be detect them, but I don't think he ever got it working. If it had worked he would have had a cheap way to detect lots of different proteins at once.

Comment: @user137 similar works about it has been worked and I want to use it to determine recombinant phage attachment quality to bacterial cell for treatment in most antibiotic resistant infections. and one more thing, I think your friend will made that.

Comment: @M007 That's his name, but I don't like giving out potentially identifying information on the internet. I'd ask you to say for me, but he wouldn't recognize my username.